# how to get value of checkbox item using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Inside my razor view, there is some text with corresponding CheckBox. That CheckBox has an id value. I want to send this id value to the MVC controller.

My simplified view has generated content like this:

```
<input id="14" class="imgCheckbox" type="checkbox">
<input id="deleteImgBtn" class="deleteImagesBtn" 
       type="button" value="Delete" name="deleteImgBtn">
```

Inside my javascript, I'm trying to gather all checked items and store them inside array which will be sent to the controller, again simplified:

```
var imgList = [];
$(document).on("click", "#deleteImgBtn", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.imgCheckbox:checked').each(function () {                    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
        imgList.push(id);
    });
...
```

On alerting id variable, I'm getting **object Object**.
I don't see what I'm doing wrong and how to see if checked id value is stored inside the `imgList` array.

Comment: _"again simplified"_ - So is the "object Object" alert you mention happening with the simplified code as shown or with your real code?

Comment: with this simplified function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the input tags in the markup like this:

```
<input id="14" class="imgCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
<input id="deleteImgBtn" class="deleteImagesBtn" 
type="button" value="Delete" name="deleteImgBtn" />
```

Please see this working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jM5e9/1/

Comment: Why would you need to close input tags with /? Does asp force you to use xhtml? Html5 and html4 don't require self-closing input elements.

Comment: @nnnnnn It depends what is specified in the _layout.cshtml, you can change it to anything.